# Service for hyperlinked notes with tree-list structure

Tags: windows, note-taking, hyperlink

I'm looking for an app to create documents and notes with support for hyperlinked notes. My requirements are explained below.

Consider the following document:

> This is a simple note<sup>1</sup>, though it should be rendered as a
>   document<sup>2</sup>.
>
> 1. A note, in my opinion, is something like a short reminder<sup>3</sup> for something.
> 2. The document has meaning that should be preserved, not just dates and actions.
> 3. For creating reminders, I'm totally fine with Google Calendar.

So here I have some sort of note which has subnotes (which could contain subnotes of their own). While this representation is somewhat accepted for final rendering, it seems to be quite inefficient in creating that type of document.

What I look for is the ability to click anywhere in the document, and open a window to add commentary (that technically is not just a commentary, it is a note of itself) and so on for as many nested subnotes as needed.

Satisfying that requirement is already great (so far I didn't find anything like it, though I've tried), but if there are many tools like that, it would be great if subnotes, beside storing as hyperlinks in parent notes, could be rendered as plain list under the root note.

I know that Microsoft Word has commentaries *(not good at all, since I cannot add commentaries for a comment)* and hyperlinks to another document *(not so good, since I have to manually create an additional document, and it opens in a different instance of MS Word; this would not work as efficient because my style of work implies very frequent creation of subnotes of various tree-like structure, and time is money)*.

It should be Windows-compatible application. If the functionality is right, price is not an issue.

Comment: take a look [here](https://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-outliner.htm). If you find something, please post an answer, to help others in future

Comment: @Mawg Thanks for the hint! Sadly, none of those solutions works for me. The closest one is ZuluPad, but still is inefficient for me.

Comment: Sorry that didn't help; but, at least you have learned of a good new site, which is my go-to for free software, which si all reviewed and rated. I hope that you find what you are looking for

Comment: The open source (Linux/Windows) note application that I use almost meets your requirements. It makes all note titles hyperlinks automatically by default. So if you have four notes titled "example", "simple note", "document" and "short reminder" then clicking on any instance of "simple note" in the example note opens the "simple note" window alongside the "example" window. You can also put ordinary clickable URLs in any note. Please critique this suggestion and tell me what features are missing. I will post an answer if it meets all your requirements.

Comment: The problem is going to be the tree structure. Everything is cross-referenced so there isn't any tree structure, there's just a long list of linked notes and a search function to search all notes.

Comment: Maybe a simple [Markdown editor](/search?q=markdown+windows+answers%3A1) would fit your needs? Link goes to a list of search results on our site, with answered questions for Markdown editors. Just take a look.

Comment: @karel Seems legit, I want to take a look at it, please.

Comment: @Izzy thank you! That seems quite fitting indeed. Gotta take a look at those markdown editors now.

Comment: @Izzy do you have by any chance any decent markdown editors with, er.. no markdown? I mean something that would be able to provide that sort of result that I have some note-entity, which contains the note itself and all linked to it subnotes, and having a wysiwyg editor?

Comment: @DmitryVolkov I'm using Linux, not Windows :) There are some other wiki-like editors (Markdown or other formats), and a few also with WYSINEWYG (…not exactly… – kidding :) But not being home in the Windows world, I have no example at hand. As for "with no markdown": plaintext won't succeed if you want to link – and Markdown is what comes closest concerning readability without a Markdown parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**Tomboy**](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Tomboy/Download) is an open source, cross-platform (Windows/Mac/Linux) note application that satisfies most of your requirements. Tomboy makes all note titles hyperlinks automatically by default. So if you have four notes titled "example", "simple note", "document" and "short reminder", then clicking on any instance of "simple note" in the example note opens the "simple note" window alongside the "example" window. You can also put ordinary clickable URLs in any note.

Tomboy's text formatting options are: bold, italic, <s>strikeout</s>, highlight, fixed width (useful for formatting code), 4 font sizes, increase/decrease indent, and bulleted list.

The problem is going to be the tree structure. Everything in Tomboy cross-referenced so there isn't any tree structure, there's just a long list of linked notes and a search function to search all notes.

Tomboy is tested to work on Windows 7, 8/8.1 and 10. Instructions for installing Tomboy on Windows are [here](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Tomboy/Installing/Windows).

Comment: Almost perfect solution to me. I think I'm not gonna be picky any further. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

The note-taking tool [TheBrain](http://www.thebrain.com/) is like a visualization of a hierarchical filesystem. You can arrange to view the tree from almost any node.

I don't know whether it satisfies all of your other requirements, but it's worth a look.

There are tutorials and a free trial, but requires a license for continued use.

Best wishes ... cheers, drl

Comment: Thanks for the answer, drl. The tool you posted is magnificent, thank you very much, but it is not what I look for. The main criteria is to be able to create hyperlinked subnotes, which also could have hyperlinked subnotes. It should be more like a tool to create a wikipedia page, with links attached to words which lead to subnotes.
If there is an ability to take a look at the tree structure - great, no - not a big deal.